# How to summon fishes with delay after player passes through a location in the sea?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

I'm using Minecraft Education Edition. I want to summon 3 to 5 fish whenever a player comes closer to a location in the sea and I want it to put some delay for summoning too, for example: 3 seconds.

Can I achieve this with command blocks or with other methods?

Comment: For Java edition the solution is here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/363578/171580 But I don't know how much of that applies to MCBE. The datapack solution definitely does not and the other solution definitely does not work quite like that. But the main idea might also work there.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using repeating command blocks, you can put a delay of ticks, 20 ticks per second of delay, then you can use a scoreboard command to keep up with the number of fish.

Comment: This could do with more details.

Answer (score -1):

Use a command block on repeat, always active with the command `/testforplayer x y z dx dy dz` then have a comparator running out of command block and going into another command block with the command `/summon fish x y z` on a 30 tick delay for 3 seconds. Or if you know how to you can bypass the comparator and use chain command blocks.

Comment: Is `/testforplayer` really a valid command?

Comment: @pppery I found a /testfor command but not /testforplayer command.

Comment: What are you playing on?