# How do i make a command block delay in minecraft 1.16

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I have tried multiple things that were used in earlier versions but they no longer work as commands have changed a lot so I was wondering how I can delay them for my adventure map

Comment: nevermind i have figured it respond again if you want me to post pictures with how !

Comment: That’s exactly what Arqade is all about. So please do that!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delay or slowly loop commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/363578/how-to-delay-or-slowly-loop-commands)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Scoreboards! You can make a timer that runs when something happens like another scoreboard changes value. You can use this with functions, Example:
setup file:
scoreboard objectives add timer dummy
scoreboard objectives add starttimer dummy
something that runs at every tick:
execute if entity @a[scores={starttimer=1}] run scoreboard players add @a timer 1
execute if entity @a[scores={timer=(some numbers as tick)
}] run (Commands)

20 ticks = 1 second

Answer (score 0):

You can use repeaters connected to command blocks set to impulse, like this:

```
Key:
C = Command Block
R = Repeater
B = Button / Lever
```

```
B C R C R C...
```

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing commands and redstone, generally it's a sign of poor design.

Comment: I don't quite understand that... Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: It's too much to explain in an itty-bitty comment, so here is an [article](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/235448/250180) explaining the dangers of mixing commands and redstone. Repeaters are *not too bad*, but still should be avoided if possible. The biggest danger is redstone dust, which can cause lag and should be avoided at all costs. *(Don't forget to @mention me when replying. Thank goodness I checked for replies, because I didn't get notified!)*