# How do you make tnt spawn on you every 10 seconds in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do you make TNT spawn on you every 10 seconds in Minecraft with command blocks? I've looked at multiple reddit posts, but they didn't seem to work. The other solutions did not work, as after the timer scoreboard reached the point nothing happened

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delay or slowly loop commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/363578/how-to-delay-or-slowly-loop-commands)

Comment: The  solutions did not work, as after the timer scoreboard reached the point nothing happened

Comment: @JohnOlar When the timer scoreboard reaches the point, just reset the score and start over. For example, when the timer reaches 200, set it back to 0 and continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this command once (by hand or in a command block, it doesn't matter)

```
scoreboard objectives add tntTimer dummy
```

Set up a line of 3 command blocks. The first one should be repeating, and all the rest should be chain command blocks. Power them all with redstone or set them to Always Active. Put these three commands in them.

```
execute as @a[scores={tntTimer=..0}] at @s run summon tnt ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:80}
scoreboard players set @a[scores={tntTimer=..0}] tntTimer 200
scoreboard players remove @a tntTimer 1
```

Comment: You don’t need `as`, you only need `at`.