# Run a command block once every day

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I created a device which gives out diamonds when a lever is pulled. The code is: `setblock ~ ~5 ~ minecraft:diamond_ore destroy`

I want this to run on repeat and give out a diamond everyday or every half-day.

It's 1.16.5.

Comment: Try using a daylight sensor. Or /time query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delay or slowly loop commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/363578/how-to-delay-or-slowly-loop-commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would summon an armor stand to keep count of a scoreboard.

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,NoGravity:1b,CustomName:'{"text":"timer"}'}
```

Then I'd create a timer scoreboard.

```
/scoreboard objectives add timer dummy
```

Have a command block add 1 to this every tick.

```
/scoreboard players add @e[type=armor_stand,name=timer] timer 1
```

And calculate the time you want in ticks (20 ticks/s).
For 1 real life day that would be 20x60x60x24, which is 1.728.000.

Then place the block exactly 1 tick before the timer is at the right time.

```
/execute if entity @e[type=armor_stand,name=timer,scores={timer=1727999..1727999}] run setblock ~ ~5 ~ minecraft:diamond_ore destroy
```

And then reset the score at the correct time.

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=armor_stand,name=timer,scores={timer=1728000..}] timer 0
```

This should place/destroy the block every 24 hours. If you want minecraft days, they are 24.000 ticks instead of the 1.728.000.