# How do i make it say Hi in chat on Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do i make it say Hi in chat on Minecraft? i put /tellraw @a "Hi" in a command block and it works. but i wanna make it say it every 30 minutes. Any help please?

Comment: Which edition of Minecraft are you playing?

Comment: ppery, i use java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delay or slowly loop commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/363578/how-to-delay-or-slowly-loop-commands)

Answer (score -1):

Use a command block with your "Hi" command, then you will have to have a very long line of Redstone repeaters, I believe you will need to have a line of 4500 repeaters each set to 4 ticks, snaking around back and forth, and at the end, have part of the signal power the command block, then the other part restarts the loop.

Comment: You should not mix commands and redstone, it is a bad practice.