# How to make a Countdown Function in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm new in the whole Minecraft Function stuff but I want to create a Function that should do something after a 3 second Countdown which appears as a title.
I tried it with the /schedule command but it didn't actually work. Can someone help me with this?

**Info**

- 1.18
- java-edition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delay or slowly loop commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/363578/how-to-delay-or-slowly-loop-commands)