# How do you add a delay between two commands in a function?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a function where it runs three /title commands to announce something to everyone on the server. However, I'm fairly certain that it will run one command per tick, meaning that the title commands will overlap and only the last one will actually appear on the screen. Does anyone know how to delay the time between commands in a function?

Right now it looks like this:

`/title @a times 10 40 10`

`/title @a ["(text)"]`

`/title @a ["(text)"]`

`/title @a ["(text)"]`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just use redstone repeaters between each command block and set them to be triggered by redstone. Not certain if command blocks output redstone, though.

Comment: @Corsaka they output a comparator signal on success though, and comparators also have a built in 2 tick (1 redstone tick) delay

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delay or loop commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/363578/how-to-delay-or-loop-commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t over complicate things. Just run them in different command blocks and use repeaters to time them.